# QtSql: QSqlRecord doesn't keep the table prefixes

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a small application in Qt and I'm using the SQL library together with SQLite as the database. So far this has worked out well. The `QSqlQuery` class only provides a method for getting column values by **index** instead of **field name**. However, using the `record()` function the current row on the query can be turned into a `QSqlRecord`, which has the `value()` function for getting values by field name.

So, this works out just fine and allows me to write shorter and cleaner code, but a join query like the following brings problems:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.table2_id=t2.id
```

So we execute this query as normal, and convert a row to a record. But turns out that the column names in the `QSqlRecord` aren't prefixed with the table name - for example, there are two columns called `id` to be found in the record object. This is obviously a bit problematic.

What's the best solution to this problem?

(I've found [this issue](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-7170) in the Qt bug tracker, but it's not of much help.)

Comment: I have a similar problem using a subselect and case statements aliased, so that my work is done by Sqllite.
Unfortunately when popped into SqlRecord there is only 1 field set, so I can't even access my data in any way (by id or by field name).

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field name is totally dependent on the driver; so the issue is really with SQLite itself, which might be doing the 'correct' thing after all (correct, as in SQL standards, which I haven't checked).

Anyway, easy solution: just give your fields an alias in the SQL itself, though, you can't, and really shouldn't, use `select * from`:

```
SELECT t1.id TI_ID, t1.name TI_NAME, t2.id T2_ID FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.table2_id=t2.id
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the Qt MySQL driver also has this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem as well but discovered that if you use the QSqlQueryModel to create your QSqlRecord it works fine:

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
model->setQuery("SELECT t1.id TI_ID, t1.name TI_NAME, t2.id T2_ID FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.table2_id=t2.id");

int TI_ID          = model->record(0).value("TI_ID").toInt();
int TI_ID          = model->record(0).value(0).toInt();
QString TI_NAME        = model->record(0).value("TI_NAME").toString();
QString TI_NAME_from_id= model->record(0).value(1).toString();
```

You should get the same values for the id and name using both styles.